# where do i insert the code for an infinitely scrolling marquee on my website?

Tags: html, marquee

i am making a personal website, my menu page's marquee starts from the side when i want it to repeat seamlessly, i've figured out the code but i have a very basic understanding of HTML and i break the page every time i try to put it in the code

[this is how it looks normally](https://nothzim.neocities.org/menu.html)

while i understand that the way i code is messy and unorganized (as i'm teaching myself how to code for the most part) i cannot for the life of me figure out where to insert

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.marquee {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.track {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  will-change: transform;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from { transform: translateX(0); }
  to { transform: translateX(-50%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="track">
    <div class="content">&nbsp;benreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenreybenrey</div></marquee style>
  </div>
</div>
```

because wherever i stick it (in place of the  tag) it breaks the container holding the image and links
i'd like for it to be the same size and position but scroll indefinitely and without having that beginning empty space